# FromUri into class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using this code

```
[Route("{id}/users/{name}"]
[HttpGet]
public string GetUserInfo([FromUri]int id, string name)
{
    return this.GetInfo(new User {Id = id, Name = name});
}
```

Can I use a `([FromUri]Someclass class)` in c# in Route like this:

```
[Route("{id}/users/{name}"]
[HttpGet]
public string GetUserInfo([FromUri]User user)
...
```

The question is "How can I use `[FromUri]`(or something else)`Someclass` in thar Route

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: nope. In swagger were 4 fields instead 2

Comment: Where does Swagger come into this? That isn't what your question asked. The docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri) suggest it works fine. Whether Swagger shows it correctly (however you're using Swagger, I guess maybe Swashbuckle) is another matter, and may be an issue with Swashbuckle/Swagger if it's wrong.

Comment: What do you mean  "where does swagger come into this?" My question is about how can I make [FromUri]Someclass in that Route?

Comment: Yes, that is what your question is about, but your comment says "nope. In swagger were 4 fields instead of 2" - which is why I was asking where Swagger comes into this. Your question makes no mention of Swagger anywhere. Swagger is not part of ASP.NET, so why would anyone think that your question relates to Swagger in any way?

Comment: nope. Swashbuckle/Swagger is fine. I tried to make request from external service. It was an empty model User. But Uri was fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `[FromBody]` attribute to bind the parameter class from the request body.

```
[Route("{id}/users/{name}"]
[HttpGet]
public string GetUserInfo([FromBody]User user)
...
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: does httpGET have body?)